# Let equation numbers and enumerate use the same counter

Tags: align, enumerate, counters

I managed to customized the enumeration, so it mimics the format of the math equation number. Now, I would like to replace the math equation counter by the one from the enumerate, `(\thechapter.\arabic{enumi})`, so that both share the same numbering. Note that I want change the `align` counter rather than define a new environment.

For example, below I would like the equation number to be (1.2) rather than (1.1).

(My use case is to number both equations and other textual propositions throughout the text without having to either use equations with text only or enumerates with inline equations.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\mathindent}{3\parindent}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=3\parindent,labelindent=3\parindent}
\setlist[enumerate]{%
  leftmargin=3\parindent,%
  align=left,%
  labelwidth=3\parindent,%
  labelsep=0pt%
}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{% 
  label=(\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}),
  resume%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item one
\end{enumerate}

\begin{align}
  y = x^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the best alignment of the items, I suggest using `aligned` in in-line math mode:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{3\parindent}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=3\parindent,labelindent=3\parindent}
\setlist[enumerate]{%
  leftmargin=3\parindent,%
  align=left,%
  labelwidth=3\parindent,%
  labelsep=0pt%
}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{% 
  label=(\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}),
  resume%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item one
  \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
  y &= x^2 + 2x + 1\\
  &= (x+1)^2
  \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\parbox` in math mode.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[fleqn,leqno]{amsmath}
\settowidth{\mathindent}{$(2.22)\quad$}

\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\begin{equation}
\parbox[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\mathindent}{\blindtext}
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
y &= x^2 \\
 &= x\times x\notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `aliascnt` package. In the following example, we undefine/delete the `enumi` counter, and then redefine it as an alias to the `equation` counter. (Disclaimer: blatantly deleting an existing counter like `enumi` seems rather blunt, and I'm not sure as to whether this has any unforeseen side effects. However, I didn't encounter any, and everything seems to go well...)

```
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% ----------------------------------------
% ADDED THE FOLLOWING LINES TO YOUR MWE:
\usepackage{aliascnt}

\makeatletter
\let\c@enumi\relax
\makeatother
\newaliascnt{enumi}{equation}
% ----------------------------------------

\setlength{\mathindent}{3\parindent}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=3\parindent,labelindent=3\parindent}
\setlist[enumerate]{%
  leftmargin=3\parindent,%
  align=left,%
  labelwidth=3\parindent,%
  labelsep=0pt%
}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{% 
  label=(\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}),
  resume%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item one
\end{enumerate}

\begin{align}
  y = x^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: modified MWE with aliascnt]